# Reevaluar if - else if después de llevar a cabo acción

Tags: c#, condiciones

tengo un condicional `if/else if`
en el `if` evalúo que un objeto no exista, si no existe, intento crearlo y me gustaría volver a evaluar el `if`.

```
Product p = //obtener producto
if (p is null)
{
    ClogWriter.Escriu($"El producto {codi} no existe, se buscara en la base de datos i se creara");
    string queryParent = //Consulta.
    DataTable dtParent = Funcions.ExecBasicQuery(queryParent);
    if (dtParent.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            p =//Crear objeto.
            retry = true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            ClogWriter.Escriu(e.Message);
            retry = false;
        }

    }
}
else if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type))
{
    //seguir...
}
```

Si el resultado de la consulta no me retorna ningún producto y no puedo crearlo, me gustaría salir del `if`, ya que `p` continuaría siendo `null`, sin embargo, si la consulta me retorna un registro y puedo crear el objeto, como podría forzar a reevaluar el `if` para que `p` ya no fuera `null` y siguiera con el `else if`

Comment: Puede que lo que buscas sea un [`while`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while)?

Comment: La idea era hacerlo con un `DO WHILE`, pero no puedo solo envolver el bloque del `IF`.

Comment: con recursividad?

Answer (score 0):

Creo  que lo sensillo para  tu caso seria usar recursividad, mientras tu objeto sea null, el metodo va a seguir llamandose a si mismo.

```
private void CrearObjeto()
{
 if (p is null)
 {
    ClogWriter.Escriu($"El producto {codi} no existe, se buscara en la base de datos i se creara");
    string queryParent = //Consulta.
    DataTable dtParent = Funcions.ExecBasicQuery(queryParent);
    if (dtParent.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            p =//Crear objeto.
            retry = true;
            CrearObjeto();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            ClogWriter.Escriu(e.Message);
            retry = false;
        }

    }
 } 
 else if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type))
 {
    //seguir...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer uso del keyword `goto`.Aca esta en link de la documentación de microsoft sobre el tema, espero te sirva.

[GoTo Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto)